# Передать значение в родительский компонент

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите как передать значение выше, в дочернем компоненте вызываю `this.$emit('get-method', this.users)`

а в родительском получить каким то образом `<add-new-base-component @get-method="newMethod" ref="showmodal"></add-new-base-component>`

Мне нужно в `newMethod` получить `this.users`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно документации - [Передача данных вместе с событием](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC): Вы можете отправить определённые данные вместе с событием. Например, если нужно, чтобы дочерний компонент отправлял данные родительскому компоненту, мы можем использовать второй параметр `$emit` для предоставления этого значения:

```
this.$emit('get-method', this.users)
```

, если обработчик события будет методом (допустим):

```
... @get-method="newMethod" ...
```

, тогда значение будет передано первым аргументом:

```
newMethod(users) {
 this.users = users
},
```

Привожу полный пример:

```js
Vue.component('child',{
  data(){
    return {
      users: ['Viktor','Ruslan', 'Alex']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getUsers() {
      this.$emit('get-method', this.users)
    }
  },
  template: `
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Дочерний компонент</legend>
    users = {{ users }}
    <button @click="getUsers">Отправить users родителю</button>
  </fieldset>
  `
})
Vue.component('parent',{
  data(){
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    newMethod(users) {
      this.users = users
    },
  },
  template: `
  <fieldset>
   <legend>Родительский компонент</legend>
    users = {{ users }}
    <child @get-method="newMethod" ref="showmodal"></child>
  </fieldset>
  `
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent></parent>
</div>
```